# Python3.6 - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Trying to do the addition of given integer such as 123435 = (1+2+3 = 6) and (4+3+5 = 12) and checking they are equal or not. I am facing an error in following code. I am using python 3.6

```
def isEqual(n):
    num = int(n)
    val = len(str(n))
    mid = len(str(val))//2
    return sum(num(val[:mid])) == sum(num(val[mid:]))

print(isEqual(132435))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

val = len(str(n)) ( is is of type int ) you can't make int[:] only with string it works

```
def isEqual(n):
    val = len(str(n))//2
    first_sum = eval(('+').join(str(n)[:val]))
    second_sum = eval(('+').join(str(n)[val:]))
    return first_sum == second_sum

print(isEqual(132435))
```

try this

Comment: I am trying to get the length as well as conversion from string to int. whats the possible code for above problem. @zimdero

Comment: I understood the problem and thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
return sum(num(val[:mid])) == sum(num(val[mid:]))
```

Here `val` value is 6, It is integer you cant use slicing on integer. `sum(num(val[:mid]))`

You are trying to slice integer, which results in error.

```
>>> 10[:5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```